# Mail Merge in Word Online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am working on web add-in for Office 365.
This add-in would be used by enterprises.

I have already implemented **mail merge** for Word desktop version, and now I am trying to implement the same for **Word online**.

**Does Microsoft has provided support for Mail Merge in Word online**?

I got some link says that mail merge is not supported in Word online but there were no clue which indicates whether document is latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

effectively mail merge objects are not available in the Word JavaScript API, however this is a great ask. Make sure to add/vote for it @uservoice

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

Comment: thanks for the info, I would definitely raise it in uservoice.